# How to return data within / with page without jsp / templates?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

[beginner]
Hi , i am trying to learn spring but without Jsp. Is there a way to return the data within / with the page like in Jsp using for example ModelAndView ? I found some answers suggesting templates (thymeleaf) but for now , I don't wan't to mess with templates. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can return json data thorough `@RestController` annotation in your Controller class.

```
@RequestMapping("/api/demo")
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @GetMapping("/getData")
    public String getData(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "{}";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are searching for developing the REST API. 
You may or may not have a front end page to display the data - then its REST API development you are trying to achieve to view/update the data.

You can follow - https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ for developing the same. For detailed example you can read through  https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-rest-api-with-spring-boot